Virtuoso Schematic
A query on schematic bus naming convention: Is it possible to have a bus structure in the schematic with 'index' somewhere in the middle of a signal name? For example: I can easily create a bus like : "gwl<0:7>", but it doesn't allow me to create bus like : "gwl<0:7>_modified" Any hint would really help.
GA query on schematic bus naming convention: Is it possible to have a bus structure in the schematic with 'index' somewhere in the middle of a signal name? For example: I can easily create a bus like : "gwl<0:7>", but it doesn't allow me to create bus like : "gwl<0:7>_modified" Any hint would really help.

No, the index should always be at the end.
